# Firebase hosting deploy using service account created from different project

Tags: firebase

When I am deploying firebase hosting, even after passing with the project as an argument, it is trying to deploy firebase hosting to the project that the service account was created.

I have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set. It points to a service account created from another project (Shared service account for deployments), and it has Firebase App distribution admin and all required permissions on the current project.

```
./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --only hosting:$ENVIRONMENT --project ${PROJECT_NAME} --non-interactive

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Firebase Hosting API has not been used in project 49XXYYZZ628 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasehosting.googleapis.com/overview?project=497XXYYZZ628 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Of course, the project where the service account was created does not have API enabled.

How to force firebase to deploy the project passed with the firebase deployment command?

I have tried before the deploy command

```
gcloud config set project ${PROJECT_NAME}
firebase use --project ${PROJECT_NAME}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps I used to resolve the issue when using a service account from another project for firebase hosting deployment - from a clean CI-CD environment.

1. Enable Firebase API on the project which the service account was created from.
2. Below are commands to deploy if you have multiple apps with the targets.

> ```
> firebase use --add  <ProjectID>
> firebase target:apply hosting <TargetName> <TargetHostingName>
> firebase deploy --only hosting:<TargetName>
> ```